# thumbnail image resized in the main page

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a small problem my thumbnail images in main page are resized, and the become not sharp the link of images is changing from (=-w400-c-h210) to (=s72-w400-c-h210) so to make it sharp i have to remove s72 form the link but when lok it in my html code i cant find it, i want just to show the same image without resizeing it and i dont know how to chane this data:post.thumbnailUrl/
here is my code:

```
 </b:if>
   </span><div class='post-thumb'>
           &lt;a href=&#39;<data:post.url/>&#39; style=&#39;background:url(<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover&#39;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
            </div></div>
            <b:else/>
          <b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
            <div class='post-home-image'><span class='post-labels'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
     <i class='fa fa-folder-open-o'/>
     <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
                              <b:if cond='data:label.isLast == &quot;true&quot;'>
                                <a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag'><data:label.name/></a>
                              </b:if>
                            </b:loop>
    </b:if>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with your html syntax- if it is a preprocessed alternative or something. Adding a tag to your post with the language that you are using will help attract answers. One solution I have when sizing dynamically imported images is to make the image a background to an element. This way, I can use the `background-size` and `background-position` css properties to resize the images easily.